# Объяснить функцию,си

Tags: c

Можете объяснить что выполняет эта функция(первый параметр =`' '`,второй просто слово подается,в данном случае буква,особенно не очень понятно в условии while,мы говорим,пока наш "пробел" не равен букве,но зачем это 2 раза пишется?

```
char * mystrchr(const char * s, const char c) {
    while ( *s && *s != c ){
        ++s;
    }
    return ( *s ) ? (char*) s : NULL;
}
```

Comment: Тогда прими один из ответов нажатием на галочку слева от него. При этом обрати внимание, что ответ @Yaroslav содержит весьма странные и необоснованные рекомендации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

условие записано сокращенно. Полностью нужно его читать так

```
*s != '\0' && *s != c
```

то есть, пока не конец строки (в конце сишных строк обычно есть нулевой символ) и это не нужный нам символ, двигаемся по строке.

А в самом конце ещё раз проверяем, что именно нашли. Если нулевой символ, значит нужный символ не нашли.

Comment: Можешь прокомментировать соседний ответ?

Comment: Хотелось бы дополнить 1-й комментарий от КоВадима.
Я сам учу по K&R Си, и там где то в 5 главе объяснялось такое: `static char *allocp = allocbuf;`
 это тоже самое, что `static char *allocp = &allocbuf[0];`
 так как *имя массива - одновременно адрес его нулевого элемента*

Answer (score 1):

Данная функция ищет первое вхождение символа `c` в строке `s`.

Эту конструкцию

```
while (*s && *s != c)
```

можно представить в более читабельном виде

```
while ( (*s != NULL) && (*s != c) )
```

Comment: Ну и в чём же небезопасность? И в чём строгость второй? И куда столько скобок, солить их что ли?

Comment: некоторые компиляторы могут вначале сделать операцию `(*s && *s)` а потом результат проверить с `( (*s && *s) != с)`

Comment: Какие? Приоритет операций прописан в стандарте языка.

Comment: вообще то когда то были компиляторы, которые вычисляли выражения слева на право без учета приоритета. Но я сильно сомневаюсь, что они сейчас существуют в продакшине.

Comment: есть такой компилятор XLC такую конструкцию он обрабатывает корректно, но чуть более посложней и не так  как gcc. Поэтому по привычке расставляю скобки везде.

Comment: @Qwertiy , мировой запас скобок неограничен, поэтому их можно не экономить. Главное, чтобы код был понятен человеку  (и красив). А убогими компайлерами (to @Yaroslav``) лучше не пользоваться вообще. Неужели еще остались места, в которых не работает `gcc`?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то @Yaroslav говорит о [IBM XL C](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/r/xlcpluslinux/) и судя по [доке](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27047722&aid=1), у него все в порядке с С11 и С++11.

Comment: Если пошли споры, то я бы ещё и в пустой  for  переписал) пару букв съэкономим.

Comment: @avp вот когда компилятор выберает , работодатель тут не поспоришь ))).  IBM XL C вроде поддерживает все стандарты , но очень много ньюансов, тяжело с ним работать. Уже как то на автомате везде раставляеш скобки и не делаешь длиных конструкций.